# Does NHibernate work with Advantage Database Server

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, advantage-database-server

Advantage provide their own .Net data provider so I'm hoping this is possible but can anyone confirm that NHibernate will work with Advantage Database Server?

Thanks